# PHP PDO - Using prepared statements causes server error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a PHP website that I've spend some time developing using a XAMPP localhost environment. It works great when I test it locally but unfortunately the same can not be said for when I try running it on the web server space that I've rented.

When I uploaded my finished site and tried visiting it I was greeted with 'server error 500' and after some hours of bug-hunting frustration I have pinpointed what causes the error. It turned out that executing prepared statement causes the server errors, and I have no idea why. The following code will cause a server error:

```
try {$db = new PDO("mysql:host=hostname;dbname=dbname", "username", "password");}
catch(PDOException $e) {echo $e->getMessage();}
$temp = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=?");
$temp->execute(["theusername"]);  //It's this line that causes the error.
```

The following code does the same thing but without a prepared statement; it works without any problems with the web host:

```
try {$db = new PDO("mysql:host=hostname;dbname=dbname", "username", "password");}
catch(PDOException $e) {echo $e->getMessage();}
$temp = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='username'");
```

Both of them work fine when run locally with XAMPP. Anyone have any idea why the web host gives me server errors if I try to use prepared statements?

Edit:

My XAMPP installation runs PHP 5.6.11 and my web host runs 5.3.29

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php - http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and check your logs. You also need to put your executable inside your try/catch.

Comment: Does your hosting provider have the PDO modules installed at all? Check phpinfo() output.

Comment: Are you running PHP < 5.4? Hard to debug without an error, but shorthand array notation might not be supported.

Comment: @Fred -ii-. I don't think you're right, it works fine to do it that way.

Comment: @Justsomeguy I stand corrected. It was the PHP version after all. Glad to see it's been resolved. Edit: I deleted my comment about the use of prepared statements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @chris85 alluded to, if you change to:

```
$temp->execute(array("theusername"));
```

this may cure the problem.

Comment: brief explaination: short array syntax, i.e. `['something']` instead of `array('something')` has been [added to php 5.4+](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php). For php 5.3 and below `execute(["theusername"]);` is just a syntax error.